# git move portion of old repository to a new repository

Tags: git, repository, sparse-checkout

I've a repository which contains several directories at the root, e.g.

```
gitroot/a
gitroot/b
gitroot/c
```

And I would like to create a new git repository from only the contents of a, whilst retaining its history. Is this possible? I've seen the sparse checkouts, but I'm not sure how I could use this to create a brand new repository (with relevant history) from a subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cloning your existing repository, you can use [filter-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter a -- --all
```

After that;

```
git clean -d -f  // Remove untracked files from the working tree
git gc --aggressive // Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository
git prune  // Prune all unreachable objects from the object database
```